# Strapi upload provider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

Im using next js and would like the strapi images to be uploaded to my next js public folder. This seems possible through 'upload providers' but there is no documentation on using them, Nor can i find any projects that use this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the recommended example using Next.js with Strapi + images.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-strapi

Comment: Not relevent to my question, Doesnt contain any upload providers nor anything related

Comment: That's because you likely don't want to upload images to a public folder. That kind of defeats the purpose of a CMS, in my opinion. Then, you can't easily change the image because it's saved to the file system.

I would recommend following the recommended example from the Strapi team.

Comment: Apologies, Thought you were a bot or something. Fair - But this causes a very slow loading time (300ms minumum)